# Comparing pandas dataframe columns using a function and returning a list

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this one:

```
Name A_x B_x C_x A_y B_y C_y
ab xyz 2 abc123 xyz 2 abc123
cd yza 2 def456 zab 1 NaN
ef zab 3 jkl012 abc 3 jkl012
```

What I now want to do is to compare columns `A_x` with `A_y`, `B_x` with `B_y` as well as `C_x` with `C_y`. I would like to have a function which returns the `Name` value if the values in the compared columns do not match and gives back a list with the according names.

E.g.:
When comparing `A_x` to `A_y` I would like to get a list like this:

```
list_A = ['cd','ef']
```

Comparison of `B_x` and `B_y`:

```
list_B = ['cd']
```

Comparison of `C_x` and `C_y`:

```
list_C = ['cd']
```

Note: The dataframe contains some `integer` but also some `string` and `NaN` values.

How could I get such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution reshape DataFrame for 2 columns `x` and `y` by split columns names by `_` with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), replace missing values and compare in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for not equal `x` with `y` in [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), last aggregate list and convert to dictionaries for all non matched `Name`s:

```
df1 = df.set_index('Name')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack(0, dropna=False).fillna('missing')
d = df1[ df1['x'].ne(df1['y'])].reset_index().groupby('level_1')['Name'].agg(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': ['cd', 'ef'], 'B': ['cd'], 'C': ['cd']}
```

Then for select use `key` of dict:

```
print (d['A'])
['cd', 'ef']
```